# Android Java UDP Socket: Already Bound (but not!)

Tags: java, android, networking, udp

I am writing a Java program for Android phones, using UDP sockets including UDP broadcasting.
I'm using the current Android Studio (Flamingo) and SDK (33), and the default Pixel 3 Emulated device running Android 13, all of this installed and running on a MacBook Pro M2.

In the startup of my activity, I run this code:

```
        discoverSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        discoverSocket.setBroadcast(true);
        discoverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        discoverSocket.setSoTimeout(100);
        discoverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", DISCOVER_LOCAL_PORT));
```

DISCOVER_LOCAL_PORT is 7001.

When it runs this code, it throws the exception "java.net.SocketException: Already Bound"
But nothing else is running on this device/emulator -- in fact, I just cold booted it.

I have no choice in the matter -- I have to talk to another device that uses a poorly designed protocol where the port of the device it responds to (e g, this device) must be this number. However, trying a few other port numbers, I get the same error.

I have previously written a C++ program running on a Windows laptop that works fine, so I'm moderately confident that the problem is in the Java code / runtime / Android / Emulator setup, rather than the underlying protocol or network.

So, why am I getting an "already bound" exception? Nothing else has bound here. This is the first launch after boot, so it can't be a previous iteration of my program, either.

FWIW, the claims I make in the manifest are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Can emulated devices not bind to specified UDP ports, or is there some other gotcha I'm missing?
I also tried this on my Pixel 7 Pro over WiFi debugging, and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaand the answer is: `new DatagramSocket()` will immediately bind to some random port on construction. Despite `bind()` being an available method on the socket. I need to provide the interface address and port number to the constructor of `DatagramSocket` to bind it properly, or just the port number to bind to all interfaces.

So, the fixed code is:

```
    discoverSocket = new DatagramSocket(DISCOVER_LOCAL_PORT);
    discoverSocket.setBroadcast(true);
    discoverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
    discoverSocket.setSoTimeout(100);
```

And it seems you can still set the reuse-address option and broadcast option even after creation? Maybe it sets itself up for a port in the constructor, but doesn't *actually* bind until you send the first datagram, or attempt to read the first datagram?

I also found that the emulator doesn't bridge to my local Wifi network, so I have to debug this on a real device anyway.

But at least now it works.